# How to add multiple homogenous child elements in a Zeep object

Tags: python, xml, soap, zeep

It's very easy to create a Zeep object with heterogeneous elements, for example:

```
<A>
  <B>
    <C>foo</C>
    <D>bar</D>
  </B>
  <E>
    <C>foo</C>
    <D>bar</D>
  </E>
</A>
```

Is created with (and this illustrates the various different ways):

```
A(
  B={"C": "foo", "D": "bar"},
  E={"C": "foo", "D": "bar"},
)
```

What is unclear is how you're meant to create a structure with homogenous elements like this:

```
<A>
  <B>
    <C>foo</C>
    <D>bar</D>
  </B>
  <B>
    <C>foo</C>
    <D>bar</D>
  </B>
</A>
```

How do you represent this with Zeep client types?

Answer (score 1):

Searched for this a few weeks back and it has a reasonable answer.

```
<A>
  <B>
    <C>foo</C>
    <D>bar</D>
  </B>
  <B>
    <E>far</E>
    <F>boo</F>
  </B>
</A>
```

will be represented in zeep - like dict with `list of dicts` as a value

```
dic = dict(
  A=dict(
    B=[
      {"C": "foo", "D": "bar"},
      {"E": "far", "F": "boo"},
    ]
  )
)
```

:yay:

also found it also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49847976/python-axl-soap-w-zeep-how-to-avoid-duplicate-dictionary-keys), so probly a duplicate?