# Request via zeep with multiple tags with the same name

Tags: python, zeep

Good evening! I apologize right away for my poor English.

I had a problem sending nested fields with the same name through zeep, zeep ignores all fields and sends only the last one.

I have such a function for zeep library,

```
def send_data(self, data):
    response = self.client.service.GetAddrLetter(
       Key = '12345',
       AddrInfo={'RcpnName': data['recipient_name'],
                 'RcpnIndex': data['recipient_index'],
                 'RcpnPhone': data['recipient_phone'],
                 'RcpnEmail': 'my@mail.mail',
                 'RcpnStreet': data['recipient_address'],
                 'SndrName': data['sender_name'],
                 'SndrPhone': data['sender_phone'],
                 'SndrIndex': data['sender_index'],
                 'SndrStreet': data['sender_address'],
                 'AddInfo':{'Field': data['request_order'], 'Field': data['old_order'], 'Field': data['new_order']},               
        )
        return response
```

Data is a data dictionary that I take values from it and send it to the service.

Here's what a working request looks like, sending this request through a browser or soapui all fields are perfectly processed.

```
<soapenv:Envelope 
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:pos="blabla">
    <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
        <pos:GetAddrLetterRequest>
            <pos:Key>1234567</pos:Key>
         <pos:AddrInfo>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <pos:RcpnName>Name Name</pos:RcpnName>
            <pos:RcpnPhone>123456</pos:RcpnPhone>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <pos:RcpnEmail>mail@mail</pos:RcpnEmail>
            <pos:RcpnStreet>my street</pos:RcpnStreet>
            <pos:SndrName>shop_name</pos:SndrName>
            <pos:SndrPhone>123456</pos:SndrPhone>
            <pos:SndrStreet>my street</pos:SndrStreet>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <pos:AddInfo>
            <!--0 to 5 repetitions:-->
               <pos:Field>111</pos:Field>
               <pos:Field>222</pos:Field>
              <pos:Field>333</pos:Field>
            </pos:AddInfo>
         </pos:AddrInfo>
      </pos:GetAddrLetterRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1):

Good evening, after long hours of torment, I solved this problem, I can’t say that my solution is elegant or correct, but it works and this is the most important thing for me now.

I studied [this part](https://python-zeep.readthedocs.io/en/master/datastructures.html) of the manual in the library, but alas, none of the solutions to the nested tags helped me

Then I did the following, I just pulled out the fields I needed from the dictionary and using concatenation added it to the field I needed.

```
def send_data(self, data):
    request_order = str(data['request_order'])
    old_order = str(data['old_order'])
    new_order = str(data['new_order'])
    field_value = request_order + '\n' + old_order + '\n' + new_order
    response = self.client.service.GetAddrLetter(
       Key = '12345',
       AddrInfo={'RcpnName': data['recipient_name'],
                 'RcpnIndex': data['recipient_index'],
                 'RcpnPhone': data['recipient_phone'],
                 'RcpnEmail': 'my@mail.mail',
                 'RcpnStreet': data['recipient_address'],
                 'SndrName': data['sender_name'],
                 'SndrPhone': data['sender_phone'],
                 'SndrIndex': data['sender_index'],
                 'SndrStreet': data['sender_address'],
                 'AddInfo':{'Field': field_value },               
        )
        return response
```

Now everything works, I apologize for the bad code, I'm just a junior developer, I hope this can be useful to someone

Answer (score 1):

There is a way that you can add as an array. The zeep will convert the array values into the repeated element format.

```
field_value = [111,222,333]
```

Then zeep will take it as

```
<pos:AddInfo>
           <pos:Field>111</pos:Field>
           <pos:Field>222</pos:Field>
          <pos:Field>333</pos:Field>
        </pos:AddInfo>
```

Comment: If I do this, I get: The Field type doesn't accept collections as value.

Comment: Found the answer to that here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49847976/python-axl-soap-w-zeep-how-to-avoid-duplicate-dictionary-keys